# Decision Tree R

Tags: r, decision-tree

My intention is to classify my dataset according to some training set using the ctree R package. I have problems understanding what the parameters formula and data should be.

```
features <- c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5","s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","class")
t1 <- data.frame(t(apply(a[features], 1, function(c) {
x <- rep(0,14)
for(i in 1:5) {
x[c[[paste("c", i, sep="")]]] <- x[c[[paste("c", i, sep="")]]] + 1
}
x[14]= c[11]
x
})))

library (rpart)
tree.1 <- rpart(t1$class ~ class,      method="class",data=t1,control=rpart.control(minsplit=10,cp=0))
plot(tree.1)
pred <- predict(tree.1, newdata=t2)
library(caret)
table(pred=pred, true=t2$class)
```

Error in table(pred = pred, true = t2$class) : 
  all arguments have to be the same length

I thought the formula in case of using training set would be the output classes of the training set (t1 ~ class) and the data would be the whole traing set (t1). How do I write it correctly so that I don`t get the above error? Or did I missinterpret the parameters?

Comment: Where does `t1` come from?

Comment: What is the name of the `data.frame` you're using here?

Comment: [`class` is a base function in R](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/class), by the way.

Comment: I added t1 in the code above,

Comment: I want to train the tree according to my input data, which is transformed into 13 variables + the class of the sample.